# News "Digest": Resources

Tags: resources

Sorry if this is a bit off-topic not sure where else to ask this & I know you guys will have answers.

I used to read 蛮子文摘 back in the day, till man zi got busted. The "digest" (if we can even call it that) wasn't anything super special, it just complied a bunch of 微博 news snippets but there was a "morning paper" and an "evening paper" which was great.

After everything went down - I have super missed his "papers" and have been unable to find a good alternative. Any, good, weibo news round-up snippets resources will be greatly welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[hot weibo](http://hot.weibo.com) should be a good alternative, you can read it by different categories.